# In Rust, is it OK for an (non-moving) iter to return owned values rather than references?

Tags: rust

For example, this works:

```
pub struct SquareVecIter<'a> {
    current: f64,
    iter: core::slice::Iter<'a, f64>,
}

pub fn square_iter<'a>(vec: &'a Vec<f64>) -> SquareVecIter<'a> {
    SquareVecIter {
        current: 0.0,
        iter: vec.iter(),
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for SquareVecIter<'a> {
    type Item = f64;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if let Some(next) = self.iter.next() {
            self.current = next * next;
            Some(self.current)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

// switch to test module
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests_2 {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_square_vec() {
        let vec = vec![1.0, 2.0];
        let mut iter = square_iter(&vec);
        assert_eq!(iter.next(), Some(1.0));
        assert_eq!(iter.next(), Some(4.0));
        assert_eq!(iter.next(), None);
    }
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=531edc40dcca4a79d11af3cbd29943b7

But if I have to return references to self.current then I can't get the lifetimes to work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

An `Iterator` cannot yield elements that reference itself simply due to how the trait is designed (search "lending iterator" for more info). So even if you wanted to return `Some(&self.current)` and deal with the implications therein, you could not.

Returning an `f64` (non-reference) is perfectly acceptable and would be expected because this is a kind of generative iterator. And you wouldn't need to store `current` at all:

```
pub struct SquareVecIter<'a> {
    iter: core::slice::Iter<'a, f64>,
}

pub fn square_iter<'a>(vec: &'a Vec<f64>) -> SquareVecIter<'a> {
    SquareVecIter {
        iter: vec.iter(),
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for SquareVecIter<'a> {
    type Item = f64;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if let Some(next) = self.iter.next() {
            Some(next * next)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

For an example of this in the standard library, look at the [`Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html) iterator for getting characters of a string. It keeps a reference to the original `str`, but it yields owned `char`s and not references.

Comment: Thanks. the Chars iterator is a great example.

Answer (score 1):

What @kmdreko says, of course.

I just wanted to add a couple of nitpicks:

- The pattern of the `if let Some(...) = ... {Some} else {None}` is so common that it made its way into the standard library as the `.map` function.
- Taking a `&Vec<f64>` is an antipattern. Use `&[f64]` instead. It is more general without any drawbacks.
- All of your lifetime annotations (except of the one in the struct definition) can be derived automatically, so you can simply omit them.

```rust
pub struct SquareVecIter<'a> {
    iter: core::slice::Iter<'a, f64>,
}

pub fn square_iter(vec: &[f64]) -> SquareVecIter {
    SquareVecIter { iter: vec.iter() }
}

impl Iterator for SquareVecIter<'_> {
    type Item = f64;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.iter.next().map(|next| next * next)
    }
}
```